# How to deploy Splash on google cloud?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, runtime-error, splash-screen

I am trying to deploy a server which runs Splash on Compute Engine but got no success until now.

I followed the steps contained [here](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#linux-docker) and also I added a firewall rule opening HTTP route for port 8050 and then run:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "http://<external ip>:8050/render.html",
    params={
        "url": "https://permalink.orbit.com/RenderStaticFirstPage?XPN=yWZiQQYOuh01zTc2PWcWRHfDUqlXTJ5uwQdFuycu4uk%3D%26n%3D1&id=0&base=FAMPAT",
        "wait": 2
    }
)
```

The result was a run time error.

Any ideia about how to do it rightly?